# How to create a fake tab with rounded corners?

Tags: css, rounded-corners

Even though I've read [alistapart - slidingdoors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/), I'm stuck.

Here's what I want to do:

[image: what I want to do]

The problem, you may have guessed, is in the middle.
Here's how I've "cut" into divs the tab (I'm sorry it's ugly but it's faster to explain this way) (**a green square = a div**):

[image: how i've cut the image]

Even though it's not IE6-7 compatible (many thanks Microsoft), here's what it gives under Firefox, Chrome and Opera:

[image: here's what it gives under Firefox, Chrome and Opera]

Now I want to finish the borders left, and right, and finish with round corners on the bottom (like the first picture). Have you any idea how I should do (and keep in mind that I'm planning to give the work to another person whose task will be to make my work compatible with IE 6 and 7)? I'm stuck.

[EDIT] After hours of searching, and thanks to the help of "Gaby aka G. Petrioli" (many many thanks), I've managed to do *almost* all want I wanted.

Here's what I get:

[image: almost good]

And here's what I'd like to get:
[image: my goal to reach]

If you have any idea...

Comment: While your images are helpful, we need to see your HTML/CSS. A [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) would also help.

Comment: jsFissle = link to other images, and my images are in my dev environment = impossible to access from outside...

Comment: You can just upload those four images: http://imgur.com/.

Comment: Done it, and updated the code here http://jsfiddle.net/uwUwK/37/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with css and a single image for the right side of the tab.

Have a look at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/uwUwK/3/ and add a `background-image` to the red element (*the one with class `.tab-separator`*)

---

If you could do with a different right side of the tab (*less elongated*), you do not need an image at all, demo at http://jsfiddle.net/uwUwK/4/

Comment: You somehow have `-webki-border-radius` in there, not that it makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated with the images here  http://jsfiddle.net/SPHnY/7/ getting closer, now I just need the map to be at the same height than the rest... CSS is so hard for me... don't get all that messy stuff

Comment: @OlivierPons, i believe this is what you want .. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SPHnY/22/

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli : incredible! You're so good! I'm just trying to add the only stuff missing: a kinddof hint... but it moves everything in the wrong direction... http://jsfiddle.net/olivierpons/cuT5Z/1/

Comment: @olivier, you are undoing the changes i make.. There are precise calculations for the tab to overlap the horizontal blue border of the content.. As for the ***hint*** how do you want it to work ?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm trying to change things to make it work so I won't touch anything now... I've updated my question and add pictures to explain the *hint*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4886/discussion-between-olivier-pons-and-gaby-aka-g-petrioli)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: like said Tina Turner: "you're simply the best"!! Thank you very very very very much indeed!

Answer (score 0):

if it should be compatibel to IE 6 and 7 the only way would be to use images.
Either as one big background image (which only works, if the height and width is noct dynamic) or use a set of images (divs with background-image and repeat for borders) for each border and corner.

which could work too (i found it with a short google search) is http://css3pie.com/
But depending on the methods they use, it coul affect the performance on ie heavily.

btw. if you use pure css3, you have border-radius and even border-image to do such things.
( http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/ )